# MVC : Does putting data in cache or session belong in controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm a bit confused if saving the information to session code below, belongs in the controller action as shown below or should it be part of my Model?

I would add that I have other controller methods that will read this session value later.

```
  public ActionResult AddFriend(FriendsContext viewModel)
  {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {                
            return View(viewModel);
        }

        // Start - Confused if the code block below belongs in Controller?

        Friend friend = new Friend();
        friend.FirstName = viewModel.FirstName;
        friend.LastName = viewModel.LastName;
        friend.Email = viewModel.UserEmail;            

        httpContext.Session["latest-friend"] = friend;

        // End Confusion

        return RedirectToAction("Home");
    }
```

I thought about adding a static utility class in my Model which does something like below, but it just seems stupid to add 2 lines of code in another file.

```
public static void SaveLatestFriend(Friend friend, HttpContextBase httpContext)
{
    httpContext.Session["latest-friend"] = friend;
}


public static Friend GetLatestFriend(HttpContextBase httpContext)
{
    return httpContext.Session["latest-friend"] as Friend;
}
```

Comment: Why would storage operation belong in the controller? Please open wikipedia and read what are the controller's responsibilities.

Comment: **[Check here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/735148/2007801)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't worry too much about where you put your code to save the model to session. It's one line of code so you are not saving anything or making anything clearer by extracting it out.

For creating your Friend object, I personally would either use something like Automapper, or have a populate method on my view model.

```
var friend = viewModel.Populate(new Friend());

public void Populate(Friend friend) 
{
    friend.FirstName = this.FirstName;
}
```

As for saving the friend to session, if you do want to extract it, I would do something similar to your static methods but as session extension methods. Just because it makes it immediately clear where it's being stored.

```
// set
Session.LatestFriend(friend);

// get
var latestFriend = Session.LatestFriend();
```

Answer (score 0):

Controller is the right place to store and get data, and populate models with that Data. 
Models are used as support for that data to be shown within views.

So what you're doing is pretty correct.

No need for the static class that will just get or store from Session, as it is about only one line of code.

+1 for the advice of Bigfellahull when dealing with multiple fields initialization.