# Using Session out of the Controller class

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, session

I am thinking to implement something like a static **SessionHelper** class where I would like to keep some data in **Session**.

But it seems like is impossible to use **Session** object out of the **Controller** class. Right?

Or may be I am wrong... I.e. is this link a solution [ASP.NET MVC - How to access Session data in places other than Controller and Views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/735133/asp-net-mvc-how-to-access-session-data-in-places-other-than-controller-and-vie)

Let me know, please!

Anyway for now I cannot refer to **Session** object in that class which lives in **Models** folder.

```
public static class SessionHelper
{
 public static bool ShowSuccessPopup
        {
            get
            {
                if (Session["ShowSuccessPopup"] == null)
                {
                   Session["ShowSuccessPopup"] = false;
                    return false;
                }
                else
                {
                    var result = (bool)Session["ShowSuccessPopup"].ToString();
                    return result;
                }
            }

            set {Session["ShowSuccessPopup"] = value; }

        }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Session` object is only set in the request-cycle, so anything outside the request-cycle won't have access to it (i.e. Controllers and Views are fine, but models no). If you need to work with the session in something outside of the request-cycle, then you must inject the Session object as a dependency. However, you're not going to be able to accomplish that with a static class. So you might instead try something like:

```
public class SessionHelper
{
    private HttpSessionState session;

    public SessionHelper (HttpSessionState session)
    {
        this.session = session;
    }

    public bool ShowSuccessPopup { ... }
}
```

Alternatively, you may be able to get by with merely injecting the session into your actual methods individually, but you wouldn't be able to continue using a property:

```
public static bool ShowSuccessPopup (HttpSessionState session)
{
    // do something with session
}
```

Comment: Cool! Do you think I can use this approach as well `public partial class BaseController : Controller
    {
        public SessionBox SessionBox;

        protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            SessionBox = new SessionBox(filterContext.HttpContext);
            base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
        }`

Comment: Where is `public class SessionBox
    {
        private HttpContextBase context { get; set; }

        public SessionBox(HttpContextBase context)
        {
            this.context = context;
        }

        public bool ShowSuccessPopup
        {
            get
            {
               `

Comment: I just tested my approach and it is working fine. But I am not sure if your approach is better.... (Anyway +1000 ;) )

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to ***Chris Pratt***!

Just like an alternative I am gonna share my approach.

```
public partial class BaseController : Controller
    {
        public SessionBox SessionBox;

        protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            SessionBox = new SessionBox(filterContext.HttpContext);
            base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
        }
}


 public class SessionBox
    {
        private HttpContextBase context { get; set; }

        public SessionBox(HttpContextBase context)
        {
            this.context = context;
        }

        public bool ShowSuccessPopup
        {
            get
            {
                if (context.Session["ShowSuccessPopup"] == null)
                {
                    context.Session["ShowSuccessPopup"] = false;
                    return false;
                }
                else
                {
                    var result = Convert.ToBoolean(context.Session["ShowSuccessPopup"].ToString());
                    return result;
                }
            }

            set { context.Session["ShowSuccessPopup"] = value; }

        }
    }
```

Notice that you should inheritine `Controller` class on `BaseController` class
and later in the `Controller` class you can do like

```
   if (SessionBox.ShowSuccessPopup)
                {
                    SessionBox.ShowSuccessPopup = false;
```

Here are extra links that demonstrate difference between

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate.aspx

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontextbase.aspx