# how to access session variable in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, session, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a ASP.Net MVC 5 web application and I want to set a variable in the session so that I can access it later. As I am a beginner I don't know how to achieve it. Below is what I have tried

```
clsUser user = mdlUser.GetUserForSession();
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["MyValue"] = user.SessionID; // user.SessionID is an integer
int x =  System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["MyValue"] as int; // Access
```

But I get error as Error as

> The as operator must be used with a reference type or nullable type ('int' is a non-nullable value type)

[SO LINK REFERRED](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/735133/asp-net-mvc-how-to-access-session-data-in-places-other-than-controller-and-vie)

Comment: `int x =  (int)System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["MyValue"];`

Comment: @StephenMuecke: Thank you so much. Because of your answers in SO I have learned alot. Thank you for helping a junior developer.

Comment: If you get time do explain why my solution did not work. I saw it somewhere   while I was googling.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt.aspx) (my emphasis):

> You can use the as operator to perform certain types of conversions between compatible **reference types** or nullable types

`int` is a value type, not a reference type, therefore the `as` operator cannot be used, so you need the 'classic' method for casting the value.

```
int x = (int)System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["MyValue"];
```