# MVC Session check if null - results in Error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, nullreferenceexception, session-state

I have an MVC Session which is null (doesn't exist) - I am checking this and want to return user to the "Error" view.

I am however getting a "NullReferenceException" error - have tried link below but to no avail:-

[How to check if session value is null or session key does not exist in asp.net mvc - 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41855490/how-to-check-if-session-value-is-null-or-session-key-does-not-exist-in-asp-net-m)

Where am I going wrong?

Screenshots showing code with Error:-

[image: Error1]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's few places you're making a mistake...

Firstly..

`userdata` is null and you're accessing `Id`..

You want a check if `userdata` is not null before accessing `Id`

Then...

You should check if the Session variable is not null before calling .ToString() on it..

In fact a simple

`Session["NominationsSearchViewModel"] == null`

should be sufficient since you're checking if it's null anyway..