# how to get session data by id as db?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

For example, we take data from the database by id:

```
Model model = await db.Models.FirstOrDefaultAsync(p=>p.Id==id);
```

How to also take data from a session where there is some data, including an identifier (GUID).

How to get session data by GUID?

Comment: Hey. Perhaps this can help you get started: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/735133/asp-net-mvc-how-to-access-session-data-in-places-other-than-controller-and-vie

Comment: This doesn't make a lot of sense. Session data is supposed to be partitioned to the current browser session. You're not supposed to be able to inspect another browser's session. If you want to do that, you should rethink your strategy (perhaps storing the info in Application state).